# Random memory acces violation

Tags: c, memory

I've this sample code :

```
map *d;

i = MAP_SIZE;
j = sizeof(map);
d = malloc(MAP_SIZE);

if (d == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

dest.x = dest.y = 0;

for (i = 0; i < WINDOW_HEIGHT / AREA_RESOLUTION; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < WINDOW_WIDTH / AREA_RESOLUTION; j++)
    {
        k = GetAreaPos(j, i);
        Area = d[k];
        dest.x = j*AREA_RESOLUTION;
        dest.y = i*AREA_RESOLUTION;
        if (Area->landType == DESTRUCTIBLE_BRICK) {      //GOT ERROR HERE
            SDL_QueryTexture(Game_Texture->Explodable, NULL, NULL, &dest.w, &dest.h);
            SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, Game_Texture->Explodable, NULL, &dest);
        }
        if (Area->landType == INDESTRUCTIBLE_BRICK) {
            SDL_QueryTexture(Game_Texture->Solidblock, NULL, NULL, &dest.w, &dest.h);
            SDL_RenderCopy(Renderer, Game_Texture->Solidblock, NULL, &dest);
        }
    }
}
free(d);
```

> MAP_SIZE = sizeof(map)

I use Visual Studio, when i run debug without breakpoints, I've always got a memory access violation in the first loop turns.

with breakpoints and slowly/constant F5 push, no errors, the loop finnish as well...

I don't understand why this error appears, the 2 loops havent 100 turns in this example, the violation is totally random, sometimes in the 5th turn, sometimes in the 90th...

This sample of code is running in another external loop, and when the first execution works fine, the others never has any violation error.

### UPDATE 1

Now, i use as well my `d` variable and exit `if malloc() return NULL`. The `GetAreaPos()` return correct value, but the memory violation always appaers on the first if condition at randomly between 2nd and 6th turn of second FOR loop in tests

Header definitions :

```
#define MAP_SIZE sizeof(map)
#define AREA_SIZE sizeof(union area)
#define AREA_RESOLUTION 64
#define MAP_WIDTH 10//28
#define MAP_HEIGHT 10//14

//#pragma pack(1)
typedef enum {
    EMPTY = 00,
    INDESTRUCTIBLE_BRICK = 10,
    DESTRUCTIBLE_BRICK = 11
} landType;

typedef enum {
    BONUS_BOMB_SCOPE = 000,
    MALUS_BOMB_SCOPE = 001,
    BONUS_BOMB_AMOUNT = 010,
    MALUS_BOMB_AMOUNT = 011,
    BONUS_PLAYER_SPEED = 100,
    MALUS_PLAYER_SPEED = 101,
    NO_BONUS_MALUS = 110,
    NO_MALUS_BONUS = 111,
} bonusType;

union area {
    struct {
        bool inFire :4;
        landType landType :8;
        bool presenceBomb :4;
        bool presenceBonus :4;
        bonusType typeBonus :12;
    };
    char c;
};
//#pragma pack(0)

typedef union area map[MAP_WIDTH * MAP_HEIGHT];
```

Comment: `if (d == NULL)`...why do you continue?

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: You should check k value against Area bounds. There is an unused malloc/free too

Comment: @SouravGhosh The code is too big and , i think would doesn't really help. The problem not always appaers whereas all variable values used are set statically; never change and sometimes code works well

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i've updated my post, replace Map variable with d, in test, now the memory violation always appaers at the second or 4th turn...

Comment: @SouravGhosh just use it for debug, with breakpoints on the puts, just to see if malloc fail

Comment: Are you aware that your enums values are not binary but octal or decimal? This may corrupt memory if you use them as an array index. My bet is that the crash is an indirect consequence of some other code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre regarding your other comment, i now use a variable initialised in the main() function, and program crash less often. You maybe right that my char union isn't a good solution, I'll try something more standard

Comment: I meant that bonusType and landType fixed enum values are not interpreted as binary but as decimal if start by 1 and octal if start by 0.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's work now perfectly with global declaration. I will change my enum value too for safety, thanks for all !

Comment: Great, but the root cause of the crash is still unknown.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes unfortunately I still don't understand this issue.. But thanks again for your alternative

Answer (score 0):

you first declare a pointer `map *d;` and allocate memory for it `d = malloc(MAP_SIZE);` but you ignore the return value...

`if (d == NULL)` means the `malloc` didn't work and this `(Area->landType == DESTRUCTIBLE_BRICK)` would cause UB [because `Area = Map[k];`] but your code does not protect against that and that could crash

Comment: I've updated my post, use now the d variable and verify malloc return

Comment: does map_size big enough to hold k?

Comment: d has 100 values, violation appaers when k is ~ between 2 and 6. I've added my defintions in post

Comment: What is the point of performing a malloc/free at each update? Very bad performance-wise. Should be allocated on startup or on the stack.